# Compare something with somebody

Tags: comparison, personal-pronouns

> 1. We shouldn't compare our clothes or shoes with our classmates.
> 2. We shouldn't compare our clothes or shoes with those of our **classmates'.**

(Meaning: you don't have to keep up with the Joneses )

I want to know if (1) is a loose way of saying (2) or  I have to stick to (2).

How about these two? Is there a better way of seeing it?

> 3. We shouldn't compare our clothes or shoes with our **classmates'.**
> 4. We shouldn't compare **clothes** or shoes with our classmates.

Comment: @Sam  Is the apostrophe necessary in "classmates' "in (2)？

Comment: Try "We shouldn't compare our clothes or shoes with those of our classmates". There shouldn't be an apostrophe. To be honest with you, native speakers will say things like "We shouldn't compare our clothes or shoes with our classmates" in informal or colloquial speech, but that is because they are omitting "those of", because it's clear from context.

Comment: I understand what you're going for with 3, but verbally 3 is indistinguishable from 1, and in writing it's also still pretty likely to be misunderstood as #1. Billy Kerr's comment seems pretty agreeable all around. In colloquial speech, #1 will be understood and #2 might seem a little formal and wordy.

Comment: #4 seems largely the same as #1, so still fine colloquially but perhaps not quite as accurate and precise as #2.

Comment: @TKoL  What if the word is singular? *You shouldn't compare your clothes or shoes with your friend's/friend ( singular, referring to a certain friend)*  In this case, what is the  correct/common phrasing？

Comment: It's really circumstantial. Singular-possessive "friend's" sounds exactly the same as the multiple "friends", so if someone verbally said "You shouldn't compare your clothes or shoes with your friend's/friends", it's one of those funny situations where either way works and means approximately the same thing. There's clearly a difference between "friend's" and "friends", but in that context the difference in meaning between the two sentences becomes very slight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not write #1 or #4, as they are comparing something with someone.

#2 is fine; another version, without the apostrophe after *classmates*, is also fine.  One version is with double possessive, while the other is without.

#3 is my preference, for its conciseness.  Its long form is

> We shouldn't compare our clothes or shoes with our classmates' [clothes or shoes].

We use ellipsis to omit the repeated words.